How To Post Process Nginx Reverse Proxy Response
How do I intercept and modify the response HTML from a request running through a reverse proxy and proxy_pass?
I have a large number of embedded servers that im using Nginx to reverse proxy to through one domain, I would like to be able to remove a certian tag and add css to the response depending on the specific url?
I know you can use the Lua module, but im not certian how to do that in conjunction with proxy_pass.
So for the example:
server {
    listen       80;     
    server_name  www.website.com;

    location /device1 {         
        proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:8080; 
        -->also post process to some Lua script or something. 
    }
} 


Since both proxy_pass and content_by_lua_block belong to the content phase, they are mutually exclusive:
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module?tab=readme-ov-file#content_by_lua_block

content_by_lua_block
[...]
Do not use this directive and other content handler directives in the same location. For example, this directive and the proxy_pass directive should not be used in the same location.

In order to process the upstream body you have to proxy using Lua cosocket API. There is a library for this job: lua-resty-http. If the response fits into memory, you can use Single-shot request, otherwise you have to stream it chunk by chunk — Streamed request — but it makes processing a lot more challenging.
